# Question about the structure of the MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My English skill is poor because I'm not a native English speaker.
I hope you to understand.

I have written an application whose structure is MVVM in WPF.
An idea floated into my mind while writing an application.

In MVVM pattern, I know that the ViewModel must split with View and to achieve this goal we use behavior, attached property, EventToCommand of the MVVM Light, etc situationally.

But I think that using together more than two skills of the above skills to handle the event of View on the ViewModel complicates the connection structure of the whole logic.

So... I curious what it's like to drive the all logic to handle the event of View into Behavior **situationally**.
Perhaps the structure looks like this:

1. ViewModel has only a data structure to connect with View and logic related to the data structure. (Ex: TestViewModel)
2. The logic of the ViewModel only is written on Behavior. (Ex: TestViewModelBehavior)

[image]

Thank you for reading.

Comment: If what you are asking is to have the View bound to the ViewModel and route say `ICommand` execution to another class, well that was exactly how WPF commands were [promoted by MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview) back in the day until this day as opposed to having a generic command routed to a callback in the VM

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand what is your problem correctly, maybe because my English skill is poor too :) but:

I think you can inherit `TestViewModel` from `TestViewModelBehavior` or if you want to have different Behavior in each `ViewModel` you can inject different implementations of `TestViewModelBehavior` to `TestViewModel`.

I hope to help you.

Comment: How is that any different to `BaseViewModel` that nearly everyone has in MVVM?

Comment: I'm sorry for not clarifying the content.
I just would like to know whether it violates the philosophy of MVVM pattern to write like the structure of the figure.
In the structure of the above figure, Behavior uses ViewModel.
Is it ok?  Doesn't it violate MVVM pattern?
And is it okay to name the behavior as ViewModelBehavior?

Comment: in MVVM, ViewModel name is not important but you should Introduce your ViewModel to View in a thing like ViewModelLocator